# Extracting data out of Pivot Table

Tags: vba, excel

I have a pivot table set up(see image to get a better idea). I am trying to extract data from the pivot table based on the country. You can see that the row country gives access to the row region, and the row region gives access to row product. I want to copy the data under the constraint of: `France` to get both regions, all products, and the sum of price and move it to sheet2.

Here is my idea how I could go about it, but the select method is not supported in the current property/method. How might I go about selecting all of the data under france?

```
Sheets("MY Pivot").PivotTables("MY_Pivot").PivotFields("Country").PivotItems("France" _
    ).ShowDetail = True 'Show pivot item

Sheets("MY Pivot").PivotTables("MY_Pivot").PivotFields("Country").PivotItems("France" _
    ).Select 'Select pivot item to copy

Selection.Copy 'Copy the pivot items
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Select 'Select sheet cell for paste
Sheets("Sheet2").Paste 'Paste the selected France results
```

[image: Pivot Table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the `.PivotItems("France").DataRange.EntireRow` to "Sheet2", without the need to use `Select`.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPivotItemDataRange()

Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim PvtFld As PivotField

' set the Pivot Table object
Set PvtTbl = Sheets("MY Pivot").PivotTables("MY_Pivot")
' set the Pivot Field object
Set PvtFld = PvtTbl.PivotFields("Country")

With PvtFld
    .PivotItems("France").ShowDetail = True 'Show pivot item

    ' copy >> paste the entire Range data under "France" to "Sheet2"
    .PivotItems("France").DataRange.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
End With

End Sub
```